# Как узнать логин/пароль сервера для подключения по ssh?

Tags: сеть, ssh, rsa, digitalocean

Есть сервер на DigitalOcean. Подключаюсь по ssh с помощью такой команды:

```
ssh -i configs/algo.pem root@168.68.76.135
```

В файле algo.pem лежит RSA PRIVATE KEY.
Могу ли я узнать пароль/логин сервера и возможно ли их поменять, чтобы подключаться по ssh с помощью логина/пароля?

Comment: Пароля так-то может и не быть как способа аутентификации. Заходите по ключу и настраивайте всё, что вам нужно, и пароли и sshd.

Comment: Зачем несекьюрные логин/пароль, если можно использовать RSA?

Answer (score 1):

> Подключаюсь по ssh с помощью такой команды:
>   `$ ssh ... root@...`
>   Могу ли я узнать пароль/логин

логин вы сами привели: `root`. пароля, скорее всего, нет вообще (да он и ни к чему, ведь, скорее всего, авторизация по паролю запрещена в конфигурации как небезопасная).

> возможно ли их поменять, чтобы подключаться по ssh с помощью логина/пароля?

изменить пароль весьма просто. а изменить логин можно, но **не** нужно. лучше создайте нового пользователя и подключайтесь, используя его имя и пароль, раз вас по каким-то весьма странным причинам не устраивает авторизация по ключу.

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ man passwd
$ man adduser
```